# Javascript - fix a malformed JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm receiving a JSON from a source I have no control over. Some of the fields in the JSON look like this:

```
"itemName":"lorem ipsum "dolor" sit amet"
```

or:

```
"itemName":"lorem ipsum "dolor", sit amet"
```

This fails when I try to parse it... The JSON is pretty long, too. I have an idea of how to fix this (going over the quotes and checking the characters before and after), but it's quite a large task for just parsing a JSON... I was wondering if anyone knows of an easy way to do this, or if there's a library which already takes care of it...

Comment: use console.log(itemName) and tell me the value u are getting

Comment: If it's invalid, then it isn't truly JSON. They need to fix it at the source. Why can't you report it to them?

Comment: You should not try to handle this. The source should be rectified instead of your end. How can you guarantee your fix is gonna cover all possible mistakes on the incoming data from the source?

Comment: I agree that ideally the source would fix it. I know you say "I have no control" - but you may have more control than you realize. They are not producing what was agreed on (JSON), and learning how to push back politically in a situation like this is a vital career skill. That being said, there may be something fragile that could be hacked together with a regex substitution. For that though, we need more details: is the whole JSON in one line, or are different keys on different lines? How many spaces are between correct values and the following key?

Comment: Some sites deliberately malform json response rather than implement any other sort of precautions against unauthorised use of a public (in terms of how it's available, not to whom it's available) API - this may be my "tin foil hat" conspiracy theory though - so reporting a malformed json response may trigger unwanted repercussions especially when dealing with government sites

Comment: @Confused - console.log(itemName) would result in an error. I have said specifically that this was one of the fields in a JSON object, not what I was getting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to basically parse around the quotes. Depending on how complicated the JSON is, you could set it up. Here's a basic version of just fixing up one line. As others have suggested, you're better off getting this fixed at the source.

```
var str = '"itemName":"lorem ipsum "dolor", sit amet"';
tryParse(str);
// first capture (p1) grabs the key, (p2) grabs the val
str.replace(/(".*:"?")(.*)"/gi, function(match, p1, p2) {
  str = p1 + p2.replace(/"/g, '\\"') + '"';
});
tryParse(str);

function tryParse(str) {
  str = '{' + str + '}';
  try {
    console.log(JSON.parse(str));
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

Results

```
[SyntaxError: Unexpected token d]
{ itemName: 'lorem ipsum "dolor", sit amet' }
```